# How to delete multiple items in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 Collection Views like this:

[image]

The first one is the Collection View for Albums, the second one is the Collection View for photos in each Album.

The datas are from server. I want to move some photos from AlbumA to AlbumB.

I have tried like this:

```
if response != nil {
    // Update UI Move photo from AlbumA to AlbumB
    // Get all images from albumA
    var sourceImages: [UIImage] = []
    for i in 0..<self.checkSelectedImages[self.selectedAlbumIndex].count {
        if self.checkSelectedImages[self.selectedAlbumIndex][i] == false {
            let cell = self.imageCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)) as! ODIProfileMovePhotoImageCell
            let sourceImage = cell.imageView.image
            self.imageCollectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)])
            sourceImages.append(sourceImage!)
            self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // Send those above images to AlBumB
    for i in 0..<sourceImages.count {
        self.imageCollectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)])
    }
    self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

and numberOfItemsInSection:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.albumCollectionView {
        return listData.count + 1
    }
    else if collectionView == self.imageCollectionView {
        if listData.count > 0 {
            if selectedAlbumIndex > 0 {
                return listData[selectedAlbumIndex - 1].photos.count
            } else {
                return thumbnailImagesFromPhotoLibrary.count
            }
        }
    }
    return thumbnailImagesFromPhotoLibrary.count
}
```

But it crashes at this line:

```
self.imageCollectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths!)
```

It says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an
>   existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of
>   items contained in that section before the update (14), plus or minus
>   the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the elements from the array first, then delete from the `UICollectionView`.

If you use `checkSelectedImages` to calculate the number of sections or items in a section, remove the element from it first.

Comment: Hi @Eman Rezk. First, thanks for your answer, but I'm only use one array as a DataSource used for both Collection Views, so its very hard to update DataSource again. And `checkSelectedImages` is not used for calculating the number of items in section.